# How to write to SRAM via NFC in an UWP app

Tags: uwp, nfc

I want to write data into, and read data from an NFC tag's SRAM.
Is there any way to do this with UWP?

I could only find classes for reading/writing NDEF messages, but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: Do you need to write the data to the tag's eprom?

Comment: I need to write some bytes to the tag's ([NXP NTAG I²C plus 2k](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NT3H2111_2211.pdf)) SRAM.

Answer (score 0):

to write on SRAM is like to write on EEPROM. put I prefer to use fast write command.
I will share here on method to write on SRAM just for example

```
private boolean writeOnSRAM(byte[] text, MifareUltralight mu) throws IOException {

    int blocksNumber = (int) Math.ceil(text.length / 64.0);
    int index = 0;
    byte NC_REG;
    long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000;
    do {

        NC_REG = mu.readPages(SESSION_REGS_ADDRESS)[NC_REG_POS];

    }

    while (!testNc_Reg(NC_REG, WRITE_MODE) && System.currentTimeMillis() < end_time);

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= end_time) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "NC_REG is False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;

    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (int blockCounter = 0; blockCounter < blocksNumber; blockCounter++) {
        byte[] actualBlock = new byte[64];


        if (blockCounter == blocksNumber - 1) {

            byte[] not64ByteBlock = Arrays.copyOfRange(text, index, text.length);
            System.arraycopy(not64ByteBlock, 0, actualBlock, 0, not64ByteBlock.length);

        } else {

            actualBlock = Arrays.copyOfRange(text, index, index + 64);
        }

        boolean isBlockWritten = writeOneBlockOnSram(actualBlock, mu);
        index += 64;
        counter = blockCounter;

    }
    return counter == blocksNumber - 1;

}
```

and writeIneBlockOnSram is

```
    private boolean writeOneBlockOnSram(byte[] block, MifareUltralight mu) {

    byte[] writeFastCommand = {(byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xF0, (byte) 0xFF};

    byte[] res = appendTwoByteArrays(writeFastCommand, block);

    byte[] answer = new byte[0];
    byte NS_REG = 0;
    long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000;
    do {
        try {

            NS_REG = mu.readPages(SESSION_REGS_ADDRESS)[NS_REG_POS];
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "cannot read NS_REG ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    //test if SRAM_I2C_READY = 0 and I2C_LOCKED = 0
    // and if RF_LOCKED = 1
    while (!testNs_Reg(NS_REG, WRITE_MODE) && System.currentTimeMillis() < end_time);
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= end_time) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "NS_REG is False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    try {
        answer = mu.transceive(res);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "cannot write one Block", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // the answer of writing one block is ACK
    return answer[0] == 0x0A;
}
```

I hope u will can understant the code , I have test it and it works . 
it is final I need to edit it again dor enhancement purposes

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, but I think it's not for UWP.